# How to calculate sum f values in columns and percent of sum of these values and based on that create new columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Data Frame in Python Pandas table like below:

```
col1 | col2
-----------
10   |2
20   |2
30   |1
```

And I need to create 4 more columns like:

- col3 - sum of each value in col1
- col4- how % of value in col3 is in col1
- col5 - sum of each value in col1
- col6- how % of value in col5 is in col2

So as a result I need like below:

```
col1  | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
--------------------------------------
10    | 2    | 60   | 0,16 | 5    | 0.4
20    | 2    | 60   | 0.33 | 5    | 0.4 
30    | 1    | 60   | 0.5  | 5    | 0.2
```

- col3 -> because 30+20+10 = 60
- col4 -> because 10/60 = 0.16 and so on
- col5 -> because 2+2+1 = 5
- col6 ->because 2/5 = 0.4

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try via for loop and `extend()` function:

```
l=[]
for x in df:
    l.extend([[df[x].sum()]*len(df),(df[x]/df[x].sum()).tolist()])
```

Finally make a dateframe out of list l and join it with your df by using `join()` method:

```
idx=[f"{y}_sum" if x%2==0 else f"{y}_perc" for x,y in zip(range(len(df.columns)*2),df.columns.repeat(2))]
df=df.join(pd.DataFrame(l,index=idx).T)
```

output of `df`:

```
   col1  col2  col1_sum  col1_perc  col2_sum  col2_perc
0    10     2      60.0   0.166667       5.0        0.4
1    20     2      60.0   0.333333       5.0        0.4
2    30     1      60.0   0.500000       5.0        0.2
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but is it possible to instead of col.... name it for example, col1, col1_sum, col1_percent ? for each columns same logic ?

Comment: I saw your last modification, but it is not good, but almost, because we can assume that my columns are not col1 and col2, but for example col1 and dol1, and I need to use your code and names of columns I need col1, col1_sum, col1_perc and dol1, dol1_sum, dol1_perc, this is last thing I need in this

Comment: @koler yup that's why I removed it

Comment: Do you have idea how to manage with names of this columns as I mentioned above on the example of col1 and dol1? You know there is only sample, in real life I have a few hundred columns and it will  be difficult to do it by hand :D

Comment: @koler updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Almost because now we have something like: col1, col1_sum, col1_perc in each column, so name of first column is the beginning of name of rest columns calculated by your code, but I need so as to calculation made based on for example column with name "dol1" have names: dol1, dol1_sum, dol1_perc, could you try to change it ?

Comment: @koler it will work even if the columns has different names so kindly try running the code **:)**

Comment: Yes, I used your code on my real dataset, and If i have for example: col1, dol1, fol1, and I use your code I have: col1, col1_sum, col1_perc, col1, col1_sum, col1_perc, col1, col1_sum, col1_perc... instead of col1,col1_sum,col1_perc, dol1,col1_sum,dol1_perc,fol1, fol1_sum, fol1_perc, so could you try to change it Please? :)

Comment: It works on small dataset but does not work on my real dataset hmmmm why ?

Comment: @koler now try correct answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: WOW!! now it works, you are master of Python :D but it is really interesting that previous solution worked on small but did not work on real, but nevermind, the most important that the latest solutions works on my real data : thank you

Comment: @koler because in the previous solution we are repeating columns values*times of column length so it is working for the sample dataset but in the current solution we are repeating the columns name exact 2 times so it works...btw If it helped then you can try consider giving an upvote....thanks and happy coding **:)**